# Trying to get the strings out a txt file in c

Tags: c, pointers, fopen

for some reason I get exeception after the line:

```
currentString[i] = *currentChar;
```

This code is ment to gather all of the the characters from a file, till it encounters the character ';', and put them in a string.
Does anyone knows what's the deal? thanks!
This is all of the code:

```
char currentString[100] = { 0 };
char *currentChar;

//opening the input file
FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
//if the file doesn't exist, the pointer will contain NULL
if (input == NULL)
{
    exit(1);
}

//assigning the start of the input file adress to currentChar
currentChar = input;

//while the current character isn't the last character of the input file
while (currentChar < input + strlen(input) + 1)
{
    while (currentChar != ';')
    {
        currentString[i] = *currentChar;
        printf("%c", *currentChar);
        currentChar = currentChar + 1*sizeof(char);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: To access the file "input.txt" like this, you would have to _memory map_ it. Otherwise, you will have to use `fgetc()` to read it char by char.

Comment: As a related note, `sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition, so multiplying by it is never necessary. And while it doesn't break anything here (because it's always `1`), pointer arithmetic does not require multiplying by the size of the type pointed to, e.g., `int *p = &i; p += 2;` advances `p` by two `int`s, not two bytes.

Comment: Also, you need to check that you don't write more than 99 characters to `currentString`. (If you write exactly 100, there won't be enough space for the terminating zero that C strings require, and if you write more than 100 you go out of bounds since you defined it as `char currentString[100]`.)

Comment: @Arkku I wonder why you don't add these good points to your answer but post these as comments here

Comment: @Ctx Hmm, I guess I feel that the "actual question" is about reading the file and these extra points, while important to know, are not directly related to that, but rather unrelated problems specific to the OPs code and thus not necessarily helpful to other people. OTOH I suppose this question as a whole might not be applicable to many others, and so could be viewed as "help me fix this code", in which case they would be part of the answer…

Answer (score 3):

`input` is a pointer to an opaque `FILE` type, not a pointer to the contents the file as you seem to assume. This means you cannot access the contents of the file through the pointer directly. Instead, you need to pass `input` to functions that read input from the file, such as `fgets`, `getc` and `fscanf`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading from the file at all.  This:

```
currentChar = input;
```

Assigns the address of the `FILE` object pointed to by `input` to `currentChar`.  This is also a type mismatch because you're assigning a `FILE *` to a `char *`.  You also can't use  `strlen` on `input` because it is not a `char *`.  You should have gotten plenty of compiler warnings about these.

To read characters from a file, use the `fgetc` function:

```
int currentChar = fgetc(input);

//while the current character isn't the last character of the input file or a ';'
while (currentChar != EOF && currentChar != ';')
    currentString[i] = currentChar;
    printf("%c", currentChar);
    currentChar = fgetc(input);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a huge saver! 2 questions thogh: 1. why is currentChar a int? 2. how does fgetc knows the last character it returned and returns the next one each time?